# Convert and Sort Data for HighChart Column Range Representation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, highcharts

I have some data coming in random order and would like to convert into into a specific order for Highchart column ranges. Any insight on doing this effectively and insight would help

Also regardless of order of input data I always want to show chart in Apple Orange Banana order with their correct representation

I have tried using maps,sets,array in ruby and have something working which is super brittle and not the most effective.

```
            headers = Array.wrap(raw_data.dig('data', 'dimensions', 'axes', 'headers'))
            values  = Array.wrap(raw_data.dig('data', 'values', 'c')).map(&:to_f)
            labels  = headers.map { |header| Array.wrap(header['label']) }
            data = values.each_slice(2)
```

This is the weight of the fruits LOW is lowest weight and HIGH is highest weight. The problem is order of data is ordered by weight so I cant just slice consecutive values of array.

JSON DATA

```
{
  "data": {
    "dimensions": {
      "axes": {
        "headers": [{
          "label": ["Apple", "Low"]
        }, {
          "label": ["Apple", "High"]
        }, {
          "label": ["Orange", "Low"]
        }, {
          "label": ["Banana", "Low"]
        }, {
          "label": ["Orange", "High"]
        }, {
          "label": ["Banana", "High"]
        }]
      }
    }
    "values": {
      "c": ["173", "273", "414", "608", "610", "1050"]
    }
}
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
{
        series: [
          {'name': 'Weight', 'data': [[173, 273], [414, 610], [608, 1050]]}
        ],
        axis_labels: ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana'],
 }
```

chart 
https://jsfiddle.net/Praveen2710/7sdqz6Le/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to preprocess your data to the format required by Highcharts:

```
var json = {...}

var series = {
        name: 'Weight',
        data: []
    },
    i,
    header1,
    header2,
    value,
    indexOf,
    point,
    categories = [];

for (i = 0; i < json.data.values.c.length; i++) {
    labels = json.data.dimensions.axes.headers[i].label;
    header1 = labels[0].toLowerCase(),
        header2 = labels[1].toLowerCase(),
        value = json.data.values.c[i];
    indexOf = categories.indexOf(header1);

    if (indexOf !== -1) {
        series.data[indexOf][header2] = Number(value);
    } else {
        categories.push(header1);

        series.data.push({
            [header2]: Number(value),
            x: series.data.length
        });
    }
}

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    ...,
    series: [series]
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nm976qho/